# How can i store images and video in Django files system by using GraphQL

Tags: django, django-models, graphql

Django models :-

```
File = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True)
```

Django schema :-

```
from graphene_file_upload.scalars import Upload

    class Arguments:
        File = Upload()
```

it doesn't work with this way. any suggestion ?

*i'm using react in frontend and i send the file like this:-

```
const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
```

Comment: search for tutorials, uploading in graphql is not easy

Comment: @xadm Have you ever used graphql?

Comment: @EdwinCruz sure ... you can post your answer ... IMHO this is not the place to explain whole process/requirements/configs

Comment: any solution? :(